# Date Format change in SQL

Tags: sql, date-formatting, date-format

I'm trying to format the date output on this sql query to be `yyyy-mm-dd`

```
(DATEADD(DAY,90,getdate()) output yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00
```

I need to remove `00:00:00`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

The format you are looking for follows this pattern
`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120)`

Comment: I TRIED THAT AND IT DOES NOT WORK. THIS IS WHAT IT LOOKS LIKE  string (case when "code" = 3 then convert(VARCHAR (10),(DATEADD(DAY,90, "data_entry_date"),120 AS [YYYY-MM-DD] SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar (10),(DATEADD(DAY,90, "data_entry_date"), 111), '/'. '-')
else

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit excessive in my copy/paste. use `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120)` replacing `GETDATE()` with your date value.

Comment: i.e.

`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY,90,getdate()) , 120)`

Comment: +1: Though I prefer style 121 because you also get the milliseconds if you want them.

Answer (score 3):

I find that CONVERT format 121 usually gives me everything that I want:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), getdate(), 121)
```

Since I almost always only use MilDate compatible, sortable date-strings, 121 is the only style number that I have to remember.

- If you just want the date, then as above, limit the `VARCHAR` length to 10.
- If you just want `HH:MM:SS` then use `VARCHAR(19)` and wrap that in a `RIGHT(.., 8)`.
- If you want to include milliseconds for timing measurements, just use a VARCHAR(23).

And if you can't remember the string lengths and offsets, just use VARCHAR(MAX):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(MAX), getdate(), 121)
```

Then count it out from the output, and change the lengths and `RIGHT(..)` to what you need.  So much easier than having to wade through the enormous `CAST And CONVERT` [doc page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) everytime I need to format a DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function, as follows:

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY,90,getdate()), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add a `CONVERT`. Test this code:

```
DECLARE @test DATE
SET @test = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 90, GETDATE()))
SELECT @test
```

Or even easier to test:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 90, GETDATE()))
```

**EDIT**

As @RBarryYoung commented, indeed depending on your configuration it can return a different date format and not exactly the one you are asking for. The use the `CONVERT` specifying exactly the style you want, on this case number 121. Check [Microsoft BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187928.aspx) for more information about styling and using `CONVERT`

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 121)
```

Both returns:

```
2013-08-08
```

Comment: Pretty sure that this is not reliable unless you specify a style parameter. It gives different results on my system.

Comment: Thanks, @RBarryYoung, you are right, added an edit with more information.

Comment: I tried that and still does snot like it.                          string (case when "code" = 3 then CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),(DATEADD(DAY,90, "data_entry_date"),121)